# Objective-C iOS App: Is there a storage that allows me to save a key-value pair data that will be available between my app restarts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm writing a feature of the language change. First screen of the app I'm writing is about setting the language. When he user presses the button, my app directs user to app settings. I expect user to set some language and show it to them as soon as they go back to my app.

But as soon as I click on some language option, my app xcode console says:
`Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9`

Additionally, as soon as I return to my app, it gets loaded as if I closed and reopened it.

I thought that maybe I can have some code that will set a global variables like "currentLanguage" and "previousLanguage" and if those are different - I will load localisation files for "currentLanguage" and will start downloading localised videos from my server.

Comment: If you are changing the preferences for your app in the device preferences app (ie not a scene in your own app) then you would expect your app to be relaunched.  You can save values in user defaults or a file on the file system

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm fine with app relaunch. It's just I want to have an event triggered on language change but I don't seem to find one.

Answer (score 1):

System terminate your app when user change language in Settings. So you can use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults) for persistent storage and compare this values on app start, to detect if language was changed.

Example:

```
NSString *currentLanguage = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] firstObject];
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject: currentLanguage forKey:@"previousLanguage"];
NSString *previousLanguage = [userDefaults objectForKey:"previousLanguage"];
```